# Proprietary software using hardware Arduino with firmware GPLv3

Tags: licensing, gpl

Currently, we have developed proprietary (non-open source) software that runs on Windows, MacOS, and Linux using the Qt library (LGPL license). This software is using an external hardware through the serial port (USB), this external hardware is an Arduino with a GPLv3 licensed firmware.

So can proprietary software use this external device and continue without sharing the source code ? We understand that this is not a problem, because it uses USB, but the GPLv3 license is new to us.

The other related question is making sure that proprietary software can change (flash) the firmware on the Arduino between different versions (GPLv3 too).

Comment: What exactly is "private software"?

Comment: @BlueDogRanch Sorry, proprietary software

Comment: What license for the proprietary software?

Comment: @BlueDogRanch thanks for your time, but your questions say to me, that i am very lost. I need a software lawyer, thanks thanks for your time

Comment: Is the proprietary software based on GPL software or is it an aggregation?

Comment: No, the proprietary software run on computer (windows, linux, macos) and it only use the Qt LGPL library (without any modification). Then, this proprietary software use serial port to send commands to Arduino firmware with GPLv3 license.

Comment: Could you change the first sentence to make clear what exactly you are asking? I honestly don’t know.